# a way to upload video to php server with AVFoundation?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I was wondering what would be the best approach to upload a video using AVfoundation to a server in h264 format. I will be using NSURL and some form of httprequest to post data every 30 second intervals. I was wondering what would be the best way to upload if there are any established libraries to ease my life?

thank you.

Comment: I Think CFNetwork library would be useful but socket programming in ios is hard for me so i cant give you much help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use NSURLConnection with a NSMutableURLRequest. Assign a NSInputStream using the

```
- (void)setHTTPBodyStream:(NSInputStream *)inputStream
```

method.

Check the documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html